# JButtons for my hangman game are not appearing even after setting button visibility to true

Tags: java

Hi I am creating a hangman game with GUI in Java and I had a problem when I added the JButtons for the letters to the GUI because they were not appearing. Not sure why. The code where I start adding the buttons is in the is in the GamePanel class and the Game, GameWord, GameMain and GameFrame classes and parts of the GamePanel class are not shown because they are not needed to understand and answer the question.

**GamePanel class:**

```
//some imports were omitted because they are irrelevant to the post

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
     //some declarations were omitted because they are irrelevant to the post

     private JButton a;
     private JButton b;
     private JButton c;
     private JButton d;
     private JButton e;
     private JButton f;
     private JButton g;
     private JButton h;
     private JButton i;
     private JButton j;
     private JButton k;
     private JButton l;
     private JButton m;
     private JButton n;
     private JButton o;
     private JButton p;
     private JButton q;
     private JButton r;
     private JButton s;
     private JButton t;
     private JButton u;
     private JButton v;
     private JButton w;
     private JButton x;
     private JButton y;
     private JButton z;

     public GamePanel(Game aGame)
     {
          // certain initialization's were omitted because they are irrelevant
          this.addLetters();

     }

     public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
         //paint code goes here some parts were omitted as they are irrelevant to the post
         repaint();

     }
     public void addLetters()
     {
         a = new JButton("A");
         b = new JButton("B");
         c = new JButton("C");
         d = new JButton("D");
         e = new JButton("E");
         f = new JButton("F");
         g = new JButton("G");
         h = new JButton("H");
         i = new JButton("I");
         j = new JButton("J");
         k = new JButton("K");
         l = new JButton("L");
         m = new JButton("M");
         n = new JButton("N");
         o = new JButton("O");
         p = new JButton("P");
         q = new JButton("Q");
         r = new JButton("R");
         s = new JButton("S");
         t = new JButton("T");
         u = new JButton("U");
         v = new JButton("V");
         w = new JButton("W");
         x = new JButton("X");
         y = new JButton("Y");
         z = new JButton("Z");

         a.addActionListener(this);
         b.addActionListener(this);
         c.addActionListener(this);
         d.addActionListener(this);
         e.addActionListener(this);
         f.addActionListener(this);
         g.addActionListener(this);
         h.addActionListener(this);
         i.addActionListener(this);
         j.addActionListener(this);
         k.addActionListener(this);
         l.addActionListener(this);
         m.addActionListener(this);
         n.addActionListener(this);
         o.addActionListener(this);
         p.addActionListener(this);
         q.addActionListener(this);
         r.addActionListener(this);
         s.addActionListener(this);
         t.addActionListener(this);
         u.addActionListener(this);
         v.addActionListener(this);
         w.addActionListener(this);
         x.addActionListener(this);
         y.addActionListener(this);
         z.addActionListener(this);

         a.setBounds(340, 250, 5, 5);
         b.setBounds(350, 250, 5, 5);
         c.setBounds(360, 250, 5, 5);
         d.setBounds(370, 250, 5, 5);
         e.setBounds(380, 250, 5, 5);
         f.setBounds(390, 250, 5, 5);
         g.setBounds(400, 250, 5, 5);
         h.setBounds(410, 250, 5, 5);
         i.setBounds(420, 250, 5, 5);
         j.setBounds(430, 250, 5, 5);
         k.setBounds(440, 250, 5, 5);
         l.setBounds(450, 250, 5, 5);
         m.setBounds(460, 250, 5, 5);
         n.setBounds(340, 350, 5, 5);
         o.setBounds(350, 350, 5, 5);
         p.setBounds(360, 350, 5, 5);
         q.setBounds(370, 350, 5, 5);
         r.setBounds(380, 350, 5, 5);
         s.setBounds(390, 350, 5, 5);
         t.setBounds(400, 350, 5, 5);
         u.setBounds(410, 350, 5, 5);
         v.setBounds(420, 350, 5, 5);
         w.setBounds(430, 350, 5, 5);
         x.setBounds(440, 350, 5, 5);
         y.setBounds(450, 350, 5, 5);
         z.setBounds(460, 350, 5, 5);

         a.setVisible(true);
         b.setVisible(true);
         c.setVisible(true);
         d.setVisible(true);
         e.setVisible(true);
         f.setVisible(true);
         g.setVisible(true);
         h.setVisible(true);
         i.setVisible(true);
         j.setVisible(true);
         k.setVisible(true);
         l.setVisible(true);
         m.setVisible(true);
         n.setVisible(true);
         o.setVisible(true);
         p.setVisible(true);
         q.setVisible(true);
         r.setVisible(true);
         s.setVisible(true);
         t.setVisible(true);
         u.setVisible(true);
         v.setVisible(true);
         w.setVisible(true);
         x.setVisible(true);
         y.setVisible(true);
         z.setVisible(true);


         this.add(a);
         this.add(b);
         this.add(c);
         this.add(d);
         this.add(e);
         this.add(f);
         this.add(g);
         this.add(h);
         this.add(i);
         this.add(j);
         this.add(k);
         this.add(l);
         this.add(m);
         this.add(n);
         this.add(o);
         this.add(p);
         this.add(q);
         this.add(r);
         this.add(s);
         this.add(t);
         this.add(u);
         this.add(v);
         this.add(w);
         this.add(x);
         this.add(y);
         this.add(z);

     }        
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
          //actionPerformed code omitted because it is irrelevant
     }

}
```

Comment: You should read about loops and arrays... not specifically to fix this issue, just to avoid typing 26 things out repeatedly.

Comment: To add to @AndyTurner's comment, you can use numbers instead of the letters which will make looping much easier.

Comment: @RichardBarker but it is easier to use `char` literals, e.g. `'A'`, so they have more obvious meaning than 65; you can increment them too: `char c = 'A'; c++; System.out.println(c)` would print `B`.

Comment: @AndyTurner you're right there - it will be easier to read at that point. I was unaware of the char++ working though... but it makes sense. I love computers lol

Comment: *"Edit: I can no longer show the code because of copyright reasons"* Please stop vandalizing your post. Otherwise this post won't be helpful in the future to anyone... (1- for rolling it back to when it has no code again)

Comment: @Frakcool You cannot make me leave my code on this site

Comment: You shouldn't have posted it here if it has copyrights then... That's why we ask for [mcve] and not your whole code... I already flagged this post so a moderator can check this issue.

Comment: @Frakcool I want my code permanently removed from this question and I also want to be disassociated

Comment: @Frakcool even if a moderator looks at it they can't make me put the code up

Comment: Please use the contact form below if you want to make a copyright violation claim. Vandalising your post is not acceptable.

Comment: @StevenCassidy: we never made you put up this post, but when you did, you agreed to the terms of this site, which includes a CC Wiki content license. I've locked the post to prevent further vandalism.

Comment: I have updated this question in order to make it easier to understand by removing unnecessary parts but not removing too much like I did previously. This should make the question more helpful to those in the future without destroying the question and making  unhelpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out you must call `super.paint(g);` it order to make the buttons appear and than in `void addLetters()` you must call `this.setLayout(null);` which will allow you to set the size and location of the button. I also added the buttons via a loop to get rid of unnecessary repetition. my `paint()` and `addLetters()` methods are below

**paint() method**

```
/**
 * paint the graphics to the screen
 */
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
     //paint code goes here some parts were omitted as they are irrelevant to the post
     super.paint(g);
     repaint();

}
```

**addLetters() method**

```
/**
 * add the letter buttons to the screen
 */
public void addLetters()
{

    int x = (this.getWidth()/2)-60;
    int y = 300;
    int btnSize =20;
    int btnsAdded = 0;

    for (Character c : game.getAlphabet()) 
    {
        this.setLayout(null);
        JButton letter = new JButton(Character.toString(c).toUpperCase());
        letter.setLayout(null);
        letter.setSize(btnSize, btnSize);
        letter.setLocation(x,y);
        letter.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,10));
        letter.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
        letter.setVisible(true); 




        this.add(letter);


        char guess = Character.toLowerCase(c);
        letter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
        //actionPerformed code omitted because it is irrelevant
        }
      });
         x += 25;
         btnsAdded++;
         if(btnsAdded == 13)
         {
             x=(this.getWidth()/2)-60;
             y+=50;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not actually an answer; just to show you how much easier it is to implement the existing logic with a loop)

```
int x = 340;
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c, x += 10) {
  JButton button = new JButton(Character.toString(c));

  final char lower = Character.toLowercase(c);
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      game.checkGuess(lower);
    }
  });

  button.setBounds(x, 250, 5, 5);
  button.setVisible(true);

  this.add(button);
}
```

Note that I have defined an anonymous per-button `ActionListener`, so there is no need to keep the references to the buttons in an array.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes - I'm just reproducing the equivalent logic to OP's code :)

Answer (score -2):

I second what Andy Turner mentioned in comment: your code has much unnecessary repetition because you are not using arrays and/or collections such as ArrayLists, but as he noted, that's not the cause of your trouble.

One problem is that you're using `setBounds(...)` on components but forgetting that layout managers usually ignore bounds, location and size properties. Remember that JPanels use FlowLayout by default and so will place and size components based on this layout manager and the component's preferred size and will ignore your bounds. One solution is to use `null` layouts, but this leads to ugly GUI's that look terrible on all but one platform and are difficult to debug and maintain. No, learn to use and then use the layout managers. Remember that you can nest JPanels, each using its own layout and thereby achieve complex layouts with simple layout managers.

Also you're overriding JPanel's paint method but not calling the super's method, something that can cause serious side effects. Instead override paintComponent, not paint, and call the super's method in your override.

Note on testing your code, calling `super.paint(g);` as the first line of the paint method *showed* the buttons, though in the wrong place.

Note that rather than painting directly on the JPanel, one option instead is to create BufferedImages with your hangman on it, create ImageIcons of the images, and then draw them in a JLabel by calling `setIcon(...)` on the JLabel.

For example you could hold the buttons in a GridLayout-using JPanel:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Hangman2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    // best to create ImageIcons where you draw your Hangman in, and
    // then display it in a JLabel by calling setIcon(...) on the label.
    private JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
    private List<Icon> iconList = createIcons();

    public Hangman2() {
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to Hangman", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        titleLabel.setFont(titleLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 40f));

        JPanel buttonPanel = createButtonPanel();

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        // placeholder component just to show something in the center of the GUI
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(200, 200)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }



    private List<Icon> createIcons() {
        List<Icon> iconList = new ArrayList<>();

        // TODO: create hangman drawing icons and place into array

        return iconList;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        int rows = 2;
        int cols = 16;
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(rows, cols, GAP, GAP));
        // number of empty JLabels in the beginning and end of the bottom row
        int labelCount = (2 * 16 - ('Z' - 'A' + 1)) / 2;
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
            if (c - 'A' == cols) { // at 2nd row, add empty JLabels
                for (int i = 0; i < labelCount; i++) {
                    buttonPanel.add(new JLabel());
                }
            }
            JButton button = new JButton("" + c);
            buttonPanel.add(button);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < labelCount; i++) {
            buttonPanel.add(new JLabel());
        }
        return buttonPanel;
    }



    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hangman");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Hangman2());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your last point may be the reason the buttons aren't appearing.

Comment: @RichardBarker: indeed it is. Calling `super.paint(g);` sort-of fixed the problem.

Comment: @RichardBarker: I made a mock up of his Game class (he didn't post it) and when I called the super's method, the buttons appeared in the GUI.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I got the buttons to appear but they're not in the right spot is there another method or way for me to put the buttons in the correct position without completely getting rid of the graphics part and rewriting everything

Comment: @StevenCassidy: I can't in good faith recommend continued use of absolute positioning when the layout managers work so well for this. Just take the plunge into the layouts as this will make your program so easy to maintain and modify. You won't regret doing this.